# Send automated email to certain users when certain column has been filled - google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-notifications

I am trying to send email notifications to certain users when a cell in specific column has been filled in google sheet. I have tried using the script recommended but when I execute the script, an email is sent for every row in the spreadsheet.
How it supposed to work:
In my spreadsheet, there are 44 columns (from A to AR), I want to send emails to specific person when a specific cell in the designated column has been filled. for example: I want to send email to Abc@gmail.com when a cell in column V has been filled. And want to send email to bcd@gmail.com when a cell in column AB has been filled, and so on. I also want the body email to include which row the user needs to be aware of the change (but I have not known the script for this).

Can someone explain why I'm getting an email for every row and the script is not working. I have looked at other posts, but no luck. Would really appreciate some help. Here is my script.

```
function SendEmail() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
for (var i=6;i<=lr;i++){     
   var rsh = sheet.getRange(i,21); 
   var wentao = sheet.getRange(i,27);
   var retail = sheet.getRange(i,28);
    

  sheet.getRange
  //Fetch values for each row in the Range. 
   var datarsh = rsh.getValues();   
     if(datarsh>0){
    var row = datarsh[i];
    var emailAddress = "abc@gmail.com";
    var message = "Hi RSH, ASM has filled a new Mi Shop request. Need your approval on the Mi Shop Request";
    var subject = "Pitch Mi Approval - Notification";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
     }
   
    var datawentao = wentao.getValues();
    if (datawentao>0){   
    var row = datawentao[i];
    var emailAddress = "bcd@gmail.com";
    var message = "Hi Wentao, need your approval on Mi Shop Request in column ";
    var subject = "Pitch Mi Approval - Notification";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
  
    var dataretail = retail.getValues();
    if(dataretail>0){   
    var row = dataretail[i];
    var emailAddress = "cde@gmail.com";
    var message = "Hi Retail Team, Wentao has approved Mi Shop Request. Update the expansion progress in column ";
    var subject = "Pitch Mi Approval - Notification";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: This line `sheet.getRange` is  surely causing an error.  Since `rsh` is just one cell then `var datarsh = rsh.getValues();` should just be `var datarsh = rsh.getValue();` same is true of other two.  BTW column 21 is U not V. Honestly I think you should spend a little more time working out some basic tutorials before tackling something like this.  You show very little understanding about how the data in a spreadsheet is organized.  This is a very easy problem to solve with the script debugger.

Comment: What do you mean with "when a cell in specific column has been filled"? When it gets edited?

Comment: Hi @Martí, what I mean is that I want 'abc@gmail.com' get notified only if a cell in column V has been filled, the same if I want to notify 'def@gmail.com' if a cell in column AB has been filled (regardless its in row 5 or 6, if any row in column AB has been filled, I want 'def@gmail.com' to be notified via email). Hope it's clear and really appreciate some help. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function SendEmail() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(6, 20, sh.getLastRow() - 5, 9).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[2]) {
      MailApp.sendEmail("abc@gmail.com", "Pitch Mi Approval - Notification", "Hi RSH, ASM has filled a new Mi Shop request. Need your approval on the Mi Shop Request");
    }
    if (r[7]) {
      MailApp.sendEmail("bcd@gmail.com", "Hi Wentao, need your approval on Mi Shop Request in column ", "Pitch Mi Approval - Notification");
    }
    if (r[8]) {
      MailApp.sendEmail("cde@gmail.com", "Hi Retail Team", "Wentao has approved Mi Shop Request. Update the expansion progress in column ", "Pitch Mi Approval - Notification")
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, the script doesn't seem to work since when I filled cell B26, or C26 (not cell in column V), the email is still also sent, and it was sent a lot of times. in the spreadsheet, I have a total of 44 columns (A to AR), and the total rows was continuously added. I want to be notified only if a cell in column V is filled (not blank). hope the case is clear. thanks!

Comment: columns b and c are not included in the range I was considering.